# Is there a way to load data into Highstock without the use of PHP?

Tags: highcharts

I've been bashing my head for 3 days trying all three methods of loading data into Highstock chart.  Is there a way to import data without using PHP?  I'm on an IIS Server with no PHP installed.

When I use the $j.getJSON() method pointing to http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php  it works fine.  However, when I started trying to add my own data (I tried CSV and XML) I can see everything runs without a problem via the firebug console, but I get a weird result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9NQG.png

Can I please get a sample (3 plot points) for a Stockchart chart.  All the samples I can find are for a Highchart Barchart.  Which is a completely different beast than what I'm doing with StockChart.  Please, I need a sample CSV and sample JSON to base this off of.  Somebody please help.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look the [docs](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocesssing-data-from-a-file), there're some demos and explanation about how to do it.

**First**, create the csv.

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15
```

**Second**, define the basic chart options.

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: []
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Units'
        }
    },
    series: []
};
```

**Third**, process data.

```
$.get('data.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
    $.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
        var items = line.split(',');

        // header line containes categories
        if (lineNo == 0) {
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
            });
        }

        // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first position
        else {
            var series = {
                data: []
            };
            $.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
                if (itemNo == 0) {
                    series.name = item;
                } else {
                    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                }
            });

            options.series.push(series);

        }

    });

    // Create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

And [**here is the result**](http://www.highcharts.com/studies/data-from-csv.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to load data into a Highcharts/Highstock object by using an array or a named-value object. The PHP sample URL on highcharts.com returns JSON data that can be understood by Highcharts/Highstock, but you can use any data source that returns JSON data.

As an example, here is some code that uses a simple array for the series data:

```
$(function() {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },
        title : {
            text : 'My chart'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'My Series',
            data : [
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0), 30.14],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 1, 0, 0), 34.76],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 2, 0, 0), 34.34],
                [Date.UTC(2006, 0, 29, 3, 0, 0), 33.9]
            ]
        }]
    });
});
```

Here's a live sample: http://jsfiddle.net/fF9Ru/1/

If you have an existing data source, please post a sample of the data it is returning. The chart may not be rendering if the data is not properly formatted.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  I get all of that, but your sample is using hand made data within your function.  How would I put for example your data above in a CSV?  Do you have a sample CSV with the proper formatting.  I'm really in the dark on this :(

Comment: Please take a look at Ricardo's solution - he provides a jQuery sample for reading a CSV and then using that as the data array.

Comment: Sooo, I'm trying something different.  Attempting to use your data above: 

In a data.json file and simply pointing to that.  Yet, somehow it still locks up the chart.  I see (via console) that it pulls the data.json file just fine, but the chart itself is not rendering.  If Stockchart can handle this data directly, shouldn't it also work in a .json file?

Comment: GOT IT!  Now pulling from data.json but had to change the date format to UNIX 13 character.  Like this          [1140480000000,69.08],
[1140566400000,71.32],          Thanks guys!